# Converting a series of plots into an animated sequence in R

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

Hi I have the following code that I'm using to view the behavior of covariance matrices using the MASS package

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

for(x in 0:100){
  mycor = x/100
  mydist = mvrnorm(100, c(5,10), matrix(c(1,mycor,mycor,1), 2), 
                   empirical=TRUE)
  md = data.frame(mydist)
  colnames(md)= c('x','y')
  graph = ggplot(md, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
    stat_smooth(method='lm',color='red') + 
    stat_smooth(method='loess',se=FALSE,color='blue')
  print(graph)
  Sys.sleep(0.05)
}
```

It would be great if I could transform the snapshots into an animated sequence. Is there some way I can do that with R?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all install imagemagick, its small and ez. Then you can just do the following:

```
 ## Make a directory to store pngs temp
 dir.create("~/example")
 setwd("~/example")

 for(x in 0:100){
     mycor = x/100
     mydist = mvrnorm(100, c(5,10), matrix(c(1,mycor,mycor,1), 2), 
     empirical=TRUE)
     md = data.frame(mydist)
     colnames(md)= c('x','y')
     graph = ggplot(md, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
         stat_smooth(method='lm',color='red') + 
             stat_smooth(method='loess',se=FALSE,color='blue')
     ggsave(filename = sprintf("%02d.png", x))
     ## print(graph)
     ## Sys.sleep(0.05)
 }
```

This last step just makes .gif out of all the .pngs and then removes them.  The commands are sent to imagemagick via command line.

```
 ## Not sure if you on Linux or windows
 dev.off()
 if (Sys.info()[['sysname']] == "Linux") {
     system("convert -delay 80 *.png example.gif")
 } else { shell('"convert -delay 80 *.png example.gif"') }
 file.remove(list.files(path = "~/example/", pattern=".png"))
```

Comment: On linux but great answer for completeness

Answer (score 2):

The [animation package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html) provides a number of functions that will make this easy. (Including wrappers for imagemagick).

Your example, creating an HTML file using  the SciAnimator library

```
library(animation)
saveHTML({

    for(x in 0:100){
        mycor = x/100
        mydist = mvrnorm(100, c(5,10), matrix(c(1,mycor,mycor,1), 2), 
                         empirical=TRUE)
        md = data.frame(mydist)
        colnames(md)= c('x','y')
        graph = ggplot(md, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
            stat_smooth(method='lm',color='red') + 
            stat_smooth(method='loess',se=FALSE,color='blue')
        print(graph)

    }
}, img.name = "cor_plot", imgdir = "cor_dir", htmlfile = "cor.html", autobrowse = FALSE, outdir = getwd())
```